# Storing resources in Java that can be also read and written

Tags: java

I have a problem deciding how to handle resource files.
We have the bases of a game with an editor in 4 separate projects:

- GameCommon
- GameLogic
- GLGame
- Editor

GameCommon is the only project that is used by the Editor. Now the resources (images, and xml files) are located in this project as resources.

The problem is that the editor should create the xml files that are used by the game, so we need a common place where we can write to, and read from.

What approach should we take here?
I tought of creating a separate jar file to store only the resources, that can be written by both programs, but I've only found negative opinions on this.
Or maybe use a common folder near the jar file. But will it work correctly on every OS if I'm not using the home?

Comment: Store the settings folder path via java.util.prefs.Preferences?

Answer (score 0):

Java provides

```
File.separator;
```

That would help you to create a Folder relative to your jar and access it relativly, without worrying about what the path seperator for your current OS is.

That folder approach might be the easiest to accomplish, since reading and writing operations can be easily handled.

Comment: So if I use `File dir1 = new File("."); System.out.println(dir1.getCanonicalPath());` and `File.separator` for the relative path that's a good way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are operating with resource flat files, both reading and writing to, I assume that all projects require to write to and read from the resource files?

I would create a singleton that has the exclusive rights to read and write to these flat files as to eliminate write contention or reading dirty data. That way all four projects have a definitive way of accessing the resource files.

Essentially reading and writing to resouce files need to e simple and very basic. If there is a requirement bigger than that, perhaps those information should be saved inside a DBMS.

As to whether I want these files contained in a project or externalized, its a question of maintainability. Do I need to have them externalized and managed seperately during deployment? Or does these files get placed in the home directory of each logged in user's? If they need to live through redeployments, I will have them placed outside the project.

Comment: I have a singleton ResourceManager in GameCommon that loads the GameResource I need on demand. The changes to these files are made only by the developers with the editor which will not be public. They are game assets that the game uses which are created in the editor.